# How can certain code be executed in isolation from the rest of the project's code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a typical Rails application built on version 7.0.

The application has the ability for administrators to write small pieces of code in the admin panel. This code is saved as plain text to the database.

Can you please tell me how to run this code in isolation from the project? So that it is not possible to write a banal `User.all` and get all users from the database :)

**UPD**

Almost any educational portal has such an opportunity. Writing code, running that code in isolation, getting the result.

Comment: Running code "in isolation" while being able to access the same database seems contradictory. Can you explain which aspect(s) you want to isolate? In a _typical_ Ruby on Rails application, administrators would probably just run code in the [Rails console](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console).

Comment: @Stefan I don't need access to the database. The Rails application will collect ruby code from its database. For example, some two methods wrapped in a class. It all looks like text. Then this ruby code needs to be transferred to the "isolated environment" so that it will be executed there.

Comment: Watch out when code is saved to database that it is not SQL as it can be used for injection, so be sure to sanitise  the input. Remember on the OWASP Top 10 the third most successful exploitation technique is Injection!

Comment: @Colibri sorry, I don't get it. Why would administrators want to run Ruby code in isolation? What's the point of running those small code snippets if the code cannot access the application's data/database?

Comment: @MilosGrujic Thanks for the advice. This project uses mongodb in part for this reason.

Comment: @Stefan This is a simple code. For example, addition, merging. Some simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, and to get a decent answer you need to be more specific, but assuming you want to create an educational sandbox as described in your example I think your best bet is:

1. Use a sandboxing library, these libraries allow you to eval untrusted code in a safe way within your application - some examples Ruby-Sandbox, Web-Sandbox - **the tried way**
2. Use the Binding class to limit the context/scope that the eval is executed in. - **the quick way**
3. Use the new ruby WebAssembly capabilities to execute the code within the browser/html without it going through your backend. - **[the long term solution way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-x8pU6mGtPI)**

Without more information it is hard to give you more specific answers and definitely you should do a bit of research on these options.

**Probably the best bet is #3, because it has been introduced in ruby 3.2.0 for those specific reasons, I believe it is the most performant and safe solution at the same time, though it is relatively new and not hardened by years of production use.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was really helpful information for me. I need this for educational purposes. I want to implement the ability to pass what is written in the web interface to a sandbox that will return the result. I will start trying based on your recommendations.

Comment: @Colibri I am glad that you found it useful and if you find the answer sufficient consider marking it as the solution.